# MvvmCross/Xamarin "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvmcross

I know this question has been asked a million times but I'm getting the error trying to follow along with Stuart Lodge's tutorials "N+1 days of MvvmCross", N=11, CollectionView. I'm not following along 100% as I've got another project that I'm editing while watching the tutorials so I'm sure I've just missed something. Here is the full error message:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  
Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<NSObject 0x796c2460>    
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value 
coding-compliant for the key MyLabel.
```

There appears to be a valid outlet for the auto-generate partial class for TestItemView

I don't believe this is a case of adding a control to the xib, then removing it, so that there is a stranded connection. This happens when I delete the xib and start all over again. I have a "FirstView : MvxCollectionViewController" and for the cells I have a "TestItemView : MvxCollectionViewCell"  which is a stand-in for the "KittenCollectionCell". I will give the source code for FirstView, TestItemView, and the TestItemView.xib below.

FirstView:

```
using System.Drawing;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.iOS.Views;
using Foundation;
using MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Views;
using UIKit;

namespace FirstDemo.Core.iOS.Views
{
    [Register("FirstView")]
    public class FirstView : MvxCollectionViewController
    {
        private bool _isInitialized = false;
        public FirstView() : base(new UICollectionViewFlowLayout() {
            ItemSize = new SizeF(240, 400),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
        })
        {
            _isInitialized = true;
            ViewDidLoad();
        }

        public sealed override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
                return;

            base.ViewDidLoad();
            //var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(TestItemsTableView, "TitleText Name;");
            //TestItemsTableView.Source = source;
            CollectionView.RegisterNibForCell(TestItemView.Nib, TestItemView.Key);
            var source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(CollectionView, TestItemView.Key);
            CollectionView.Source = source;

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
                             set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.TestItemViewModels);
            set.Apply();
            CollectionView.ReloadData();
          }
    }
}
```

Here is *my* hand-coded partial for TestItemView:

```
using System;
using FirstDemo.Core.ViewModels;
using Foundation;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Views;
using UIKit;

namespace FirstDemo.Core.iOS
{
    public partial class TestItemView : MvxCollectionViewCell
    {
        public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("TestItemView", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("TestItemView");

        public TestItemView(IntPtr handle)
            : base(string.Empty /* TODO - this isn't really needed - mvx bug */, handle)
        {
            this.DelayBind(() =>
            {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TestItemView, TestItemViewModel>();
                set.Bind(MyLabel).To(testItem => testItem.Name);
                set.Apply();
            });
        }

        public static TestItemView Create()
        {
            return (TestItemView)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the auto-generated partial:

```
// WARNING
//
// This file has been generated automatically by Xamarin Studio from the outlets and
// actions declared in your storyboard file.
// Manual changes to this file will not be maintained.
//
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;

namespace FirstDemo.Core.iOS
{
    [Register ("TestItemView")]
    partial class TestItemView
    {
        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UILabel MyLabel { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIView TestItemInfo { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (MyLabel != null) {
                MyLabel.Dispose ();
                MyLabel = null;
            }
            if (TestItemInfo != null) {
                TestItemInfo.Dispose ();
                TestItemInfo = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the notorious xib for TestItemView:

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6211" systemVersion="14A298i" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES"><dependencies><plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6204"/></dependencies><objects><placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="TestItemView"><connections><outlet property="MyLabel" destination="28" id="name-outlet-28"/><outlet property="TestItemInfo" destination="1" id="name-outlet-1"/></connections></placeholder><placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/><view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="1"><rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/><autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/><color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/><subviews><label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" minimumFontSize="10" id="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES"><rect key="frame" x="235" y="172" width="42" height="21"/><color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/><fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/><color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/><nil key="highlightedColor"/></label></subviews><userDefinedRuntimeAttributes><userDefinedRuntimeAttribute keyPath="accessibilityIdentifier" type="string" value="MyTestItem"/></userDefinedRuntimeAttributes></view></objects></document>
```

If anyone has a clue, I'd appreciate the help because I'm at a complete loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with the swift approach. But in objective-c, you have to manually add outlet object from XIB to code. And when your XIB's view is linked to some older view's address this error will appear. So in objective-c we used to do the below steps.

- open you XIB
- search for the label with name MyLabel
- verify the connection(which object it is linked to)
- if needed, remove the outlet linking and add that once again.